# Symfony2, Doctrine 2: getResult Object

Tags: doctrine-orm, symfony

```
$posts = $em->find('Application\BlogBundle\Entity\Post',1);
print_r ($posts);
```

Why I got it?

```
Barii\BlogBundle\Entity\Post Object ( [id:Barii\BlogBundle\Entity\Post:private] => 1 [title:Application\BlogBundle\Entity\Post:private] => something [body:Application\BlogBundle\Entity\Post:private] => content  )
```

instead of a simple array like this:

```
array ( [id] => 1,
        [title] => "something",            
        [body] => "content"  )
```

I use it with Symfony 2.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have a couple options here. As far as I know, you can't find results as arrays from entity repositories by default. Instead, you can do one of two things:

First, you could implement a `toArray()` method on your entity object (perhaps through a [mapped superclass](http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.0/en/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#mapped-superclasses)) that simply returns an array of properties.

Second, you could use Doctrine Query Language to pull the information that you need using the `getArrayResult()` method, perhaps something like this:

```
$query = $em->createQuery('SELECT p FROM Application\BlogBundle\Entity\Post p WHERE p.id=:pid');
$query->setParameter('tid', $postId);
$result = $query->getArrayResult(); // shortcut for $query->getResult(Query::HYDRATE_ARRAY);
```

More in-depth documentation on DQL can be found [here](http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.0/en/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html).

Comment: It is disappointing that Sf2/Doctrine doesn't anticipate this extremely common use case.