# Symfony 2 PHP Template Engine rendering Objects

Tags: php, symfony, twig, templating-engine

I kind of prefer using PHP Template Engine to Twig in symfony2 due to some flexibility, and something I am more used to.

For instance, I will like to use things like 'ternary If' when printing out some stuff.

My problem now is that, My data got rendered on the template as Objects. using (array) seems not to help as well as I ended up getting things like;

```
array (size=4)
 '�news\newsBundle\Entity\News�id' => int 1
 '�news\newsBundle\Entity\News�title' => string 'News title 1' (length=12)
 '�news\newsBundle\Entity\News�body' => string 'Some body text' (length=14)
 '�news\newsBundle\Entity\News�createdDate' => 
  object(DateTime)[306]
  public 'date' => string '2014-11-05 19:41:48.000000' (length=26)
  public 'timezone_type' => int 3
  public 'timezone' => string 'Europe/London' (length=13)
```

How do I get results like a normal array e.g array('id'=> int 1) without the namespace stuff in it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: `twig` also supports `ternary if` - http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/templates.html#other-operators

Answer (score 0):

You may want to change hydration mode in your queries to get entities as arrays:

http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#array-hydration

[Symfony2, Doctrine 2: getResult Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6004325/symfony2-doctrine-2-getresult-object)